# pandas: merge dataframes and include index as a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like the following:

```
df1:
   dp  value
0  d1      2
1  d1      3
2  d2      7
3  d2      8
4  d3      6

df2:
  fv_name  dp  value
0     x-1  d1      2
1     x-2  d1      2
2     x-3  d1      3
3     x-1  d2      7
4     x-2  d2      7
5     x-3  d2      8
6     x-1  d3      6
7     x-2  d3      6
8     x-3  d3      6
```

And I am trying to add the indices from df1 onto df2 to produce a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df3:
  fv_name  dp  value   dp_id
0     x-1  d1      2    0
1     x-2  d1      2    0
2     x-3  d1      3    1
3     x-1  d2      7    2
4     x-2  d2      7    2
5     x-3  d2      8    3
6     x-1  d3      6    4
7     x-2  d3      6    4
8     x-3  d3      6    4
```

I was attempting some different types of merges like the following, but I am unable to achieve my desired dataframe.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['dp', 'value'], how='outer')
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Promote the index of d1 to a column, then perform the merge:

```
df1['dp_id'] = df1.index
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['dp', 'value'], how='outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) & [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1.rename_axis('dp_id').reset_index(), df2,  
                                           on=['dp', 'value'], how='outer')
```